# URL amazon API - Item lookup not valid for this endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services

So I'm having trouble making an API request to amazon and returning XML that displays product information, particularly price. I'm using the signed request helper to generate my requests, and have been following the examples in the AWS documentation.

here is my request URL and params:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
  Service=AWSECommerceService
  &Operation=ItemLookup
  &ResponseGroup=OfferFull
  &Condition=All
  &IdType=ASIN
  &ItemId=B001L8NG0Q
```

the helper also generates my signature, access keys, etc. However this is what is returned what I submit this request:

```
  <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
    <Error>
    <Code>InvalidAction</Code>
    <Message>
    The action ItemLookup is not valid for this endpoint.
    </Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>a006f1ec-11b3-4afd-a5a3-cb8cfd7e4186</RequestId>
    </ErrorResponse>
```

Any ideas on what my problem is here? I seem to be able to get this to work just fine for keyword queries, but i'm having trouble with this item lookup.